# How can you use an immutable object in the case of an order or trade object?

Tags: immutability

I have read that ideally all objects should be immutable. But say you have an object like an order or trade the state of which will change when, for example, the order is fulfilled or the trade executed? I would have at one time never considered using an immutable object for representing such real-world entities and wonder how this could be done in an effective way.

Answer (score 0):

With immutable datastructures, whenever you 'change' on object, really the old one stays as it was . You receive a new object, that shares all properties with the old object except the ones you updated

Comment: But it seems like more than one thread would be operating on the same object -- the user might cancel a trade and a broker might execute a trade -- I think this implies you would want a single object throughout the lifetime of the trade.

Comment: one of the benefits of immutable objects is that their identity IS their state, if you wanted to make sure you don't process an order in some way if it is complete, you could maybe store the finished orders in a set or some other data structure, and just look to see if the order is in the set of finished orders, you wouldn't even need to have a field that needs to change.

Comment: @chatton: what happens to a list of open orders in an account in this design? The original order is deleted and a new order added to the finished list?

Comment: well in this case the order is still the same object, so you could maybe remove it from a queue of active orders, and add it to a collection of finished orders. Any given order doesn't really need to know if itself is finished, you can determine this by how you store it. For example, if you need to re open an order, you can just grab it from the completed orders and then add it to the queue of un processed orders. It's the same object the entire time.

Comment: @chatton: Does object persistence using JPA have any bearing in this? Separate tables for completed and new orders?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar enough with JPA to be able to give you an informed answer!